# MongoDB - How to match the value of a field with nested document field value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a structure where I want to match the value of a field on root level with the value of a field inside another object in the same document, I got to his structure by unwinding on the nested field. So I have a structure like this:

```
{
   "name": "somename",
   "level": "123",
   "nested":[ 
        {
          "somefield": "test",
          "file": {
             level:"123"
          }
     },
     {
         "somefield": "test2",
         "file": {
            level:"124"
        }
     }
  ]
}
```

After unwinding I got the structure like:

```
{
   "name": "somename",
   "level": "123",
   "nested": {
      "somefield": "test",
      "file": {
         level:"123"
       }
    }
}
```

So I want to match on `level = nested.file.level` and return only documents which satisfy this condition.

I tried using

```
$match: {
    "nested.file.level": '$level'
}
```

also

```
$project: {
    nested: {
        $cond: [{
                $eq: [
                    'nested.file.level',
                    '$level'
                ]
            },
            '$nested',
            null
        ]
    }
}
```

Nothing seems to work. Any idea on how I can match based on the mentioned criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1: With `$unwind` stage**

After `$unwind` stage, in the `$match` stage you need to use the `$expr` operator.

```
{
  $match: {
    $expr: {
      $eq: [
        "$nested.file.level",
        "$level"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo Solution 1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-dTCT5GpChe)

---

**Solution 2: Without `$unwind` stage**

Without `$unwind` stage, you may work with `$filter` operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $in: [
          "$level",
          "$nested.file.level"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      nested: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$nested",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.file.level",
              "$level"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Solution 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n6wvnHPgJ9U)

Comment: This worked for me thank you. I also have another use case where I want to add a new field inside the document when using $switch is that possible?

Comment: I think will be great if you can create another question by listing down the requirement, and sharing the input and expected output documents.

Comment: I have added a new question can you please have a look
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73444202/mongodb-best-way-to-choose-a-document-based-on-some-condition-inside-switch-ca