# MongoDB - Best way to choose a document based on some condition inside switch case

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a structure where I want to match the value of a field on root level with the value of a field inside another object in the same document and then choose a single document based on some condition from the result. This is the structure I have:

```
{
   "name": "somename",
   "level": "123",
   "nested":[ 
        {
          "somefield": "test",
          "file": {
             level:"123"
         }
     },
     {
         "somefield": "test2",
         "file": {
            level:"124"
         }
     },
     {
         "somefield": "test3",
         "file": {
            level:"123"
         }
     }
  ]
}
```

After unwinding and matching it on a condition (`level = nested.file.level`) I have left with 2 documents:

```
[
  {
    "level": "123",
    "name": "somename",
    "nested": {
      "file": {
        "level": "123"
      },
      "somefield": "test"
    }
  },
  {
    "level": "123",
    "name": "somename",
    "nested": {
      "file": {
        "level": "123"
      },
      "somefield": "test3"
    }
  }
]
```

Now I want to match on `somefield`  values, this field has 10 different values, these values are in order so if I find a matching document then I will return it or I will go to the next value in the order and check if `"somefield": "orderedValue"` and so on. So for example:

```
test
test2
test3
test4
test5
```

is the order and if I find a document with has `"somefield": "test"` I will only return that document, else I will check for `"somefield": "test2"` and so on until I find a single document which satisfies my condition. This is done in order so the first to satisfy the condition that the document I want.

I want to get only 1 document in the end as a result. I thought it would be best to use `$switch` here and wrote a project stage with $switch.

```
$project: {
        setting: {
            $switch: {
                branches: [{
                        'case': {
                            $eq: [
                                '$nested.somefield',
                                'test'
                            ]
                        },
                        then: '$nested'
                    },
                    {
                        'case': {
                            $eq: [
                                '$nested.somefield',
                                'test2'
                            ]
                        },
                        then: '$nested'
                    },
                    {
                        'case': {
                            $eq: [
                                '$nested.somefield',
                                'test3'
                            ]
                        },
                        then: '$nested'
                    }
                ],
                'default': 'Did not match'
            }
        }
    }
```

But this won't work as this would be applied on each document and if I have 5 documents with 5 of these values then it will match all of them and return the same array of documents. Any idea on how we can return only the document which matched first?

Comment: You can add a {$limit: 1}, to return only the first matching document

Comment: The problem is that the project stage with switch will be applied on all the documents individually so if I have 5 document with all the 5 values as I mentioned, then for each document the switch will be performed and all the 5 are returned back. so switch is not a good choice here. What I want to know is how can I do it in a way that all the documents are checked once and only return the first matching document.

Comment: All the documents reaching a particular stage will pass through that stage.  You cannot apply a stage conditionally. It's only in the next stage, the filtered documents or limited documents will go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1: With `$switch` operator**

3rd stage: `$set` - Create `min` field and assign the value based on `$switch` operator.

4th stage: `$sort` - Order by `min` ascending.

5th stage: `$limit` - Limit to 1 document.

6th stage: `$group` - Group by `$_id`. Set the `setting` field by taking the first document/value with the conditions:

1. If the `min` is lesser than or equal to 5, take `nested` value.
2. Else, get "Did not match" value.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$nested"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          "$nested.file.level",
          "$level"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      min: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              "case": {
                $eq: [
                  "$nested.somefield",
                  "test"
                ]
              },
              then: 1
            },
            {
              "case": {
                $eq: [
                  "$nested.somefield",
                  "test2"
                ]
              },
              then: 2
            },
            {
              "case": {
                $eq: [
                  "$nested.somefield",
                  "test3"
                ]
              },
              then: 3
            },
            {
              "case": {
                $eq: [
                  "$nested.somefield",
                  "test4"
                ]
              },
              then: 4
            },
            {
              "case": {
                $eq: [
                  "$nested.somefield",
                  "test5"
                ]
              },
              then: 5
            }
          ],
          "default": 100
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      min: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      setting: {
        $first: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $lte: [
                "$min",
                5
              ]
            },
            then: "$nested",
            else: "Did not match"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Solution 1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/H3IRnQTfcn1)

---

**Solution 2: With `$let` operator**

3rd stage: `$set` - Create `min` field. Declare the `index` variable via `$let` with get the array index by `nested.somefield`.

4th stage: `$sort` - Order by `min` ascending.

5th stage: `$limit` - Limit to 1 document.

6th stage: `$group` - Group by `$_id`. Set the `setting` field by taking the first document/value with the conditions:

1. If the `min` is greater than or equal to 0, take `nested` value.
2. Else, get "Did not match" value.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$nested"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          "$nested.file.level",
          "$level"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      min: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            index: {
              $indexOfArray: [
                [
                  "test",
                  "test2",
                  "test3",
                  "test4",
                  "test5"
                ],
                "$nested.somefield"
              ]
            }
          },
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $gt: [
                  "$$index",
                  -1
                ]
              },
              then: "$$index",
              else: 100
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      min: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      setting: {
        $first: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $lte: [
                "$min",
                4
              ]
            },
            then: "$nested",
            else: "Did not match"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Solution 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ds9WYkA6M-8)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much. I would go with the 2nd approach because its much cleaner than switch. I really appreciate your help.